# Is there an online wallet service that will allow me to access an rpc server?

Tags: bitcoind, e-wallet, ecommerce

Let's say I have an online eCommerce solution running with a plugin that is designed to connect to a bitcoin daemon running on the same server, but I am too cheap to hire a vps or dedicated server, so instead I want to use an e-wallet service. Is there one operating that will give me a server address, username and password?

Answer (score 4):

It isn't free, but:
 - http://www.microthosting.com/bitcoin-servers.html

http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BitCoinD_Cloud_Hosting

Comment: Hmmm... That would work! But a fiver/month seems so unnecessary...

Comment: I just went nuts and hired a vps. Now I can ditch the crappy web-host and stick Apache and the daemon on it. Thanks for your answer!